# Pretty URL to string parameters

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting, front-controller

I have a website that use this style : `/index.php?page=45&info=whatever&anotherparam=2`

I plan to have pretty url to transform the previous url to : `/profile/whatever/2`

I know I have to use .htAccess and to redirect everything to index.php. That's fine.

My problem is more in the index.php (Front Controller). How can I build back the `$_GET["info"]` and `$_GET["anotherparam"]` to be able to continue to use all the existing code that use `$_GET[...]` in their page?

Do I have to build back the GET in the header with some code or do I have to get rid of all `$_GET[...]` on every pages by creating my own array that will parse ever `/` to and assign something like : `$myParam["info"] = "whatever"` and than in the page use `$myParam[]` instead of `$_GET[]` ?

*I would like not to modify all those pages that use `$_GET[]`*

#### Edit:

My .htAccess look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Everything that doesn't exist go to index.php. Since I already use this structure :  `/index.php?page=45&info=whatever&anotherparam=2` nothing is broken. But now I will use `/profile/whatever/2` and in the switch case I can determine what page to `include(..)` but the problem is with all GET parameters. How do I build them to have access from all page with $_GET[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path = ... // wherever you get the path $_SERVER[...], etc.
            // eg: /profile/wathever

$segments = split ($path);

$segments_name = Array ('page', 'info', 'anotherparam');
for($i=0;$i  < count ($segments); $i++) {
  $_GET[$segments_name[$i]] = $segments[$i];
}
```

with this solution you have to always use the same arguments at the same position

if you don't want that you have two solution:
 - use path like /page/profile/info/wathever
 - use router system (for that I recommend you to use a framework instead of doing it all manually)

edit: second solution

```
$path = ... // wherever you get the path $_SERVER[...], etc.
            // eg: /page/profile/info/wathever
$segments = split ($path);

for($i=0;$i  < count ($segments); $i+=2) {
  $_GET[$segments[$i]] = $segments[$i+1];
}
```

Comment: I like the second solution but do not see why I shouldn't do it myself and that I should implement a framework?

Comment: edit it's the router solution that might be complex, give a look at that: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html
of course you can do it, it's just more ccomplicated

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statement instead. Also remember to modify your .htaccess

```
<?php
switch ($_GET) {
    case "home":
     header('Location: /home/');
        break;
    case "customer":
        header('Location: /customer/');
        break;
    case "profile":
        header('Location: /profile/');
        break;
}
?>
```